Using Power Query to unpivot table
Original




ID
Type 1
Count 1
Type 2
Count 2
Type 3
Count 3




1
a
640
d
Type 3
a



2
d
12000
a
1900
f
6000


3
f
48000
f
3600
e
1600


4
c
46000
e
3100
b
1200


5
e
47000
c
3400
d
1400


6
b
64000
b
3600
c
1200



I would like to create to transform the table above using Power Query into the following table:

In reality, I have 6 different types with a lot of data. Any help on how to do this?

You can try
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
base_columns=1, groupsof=2, 
Combo = List.Transform(List.Split(List.Skip(Table.ColumnNames(Source),base_columns),groupsof), each List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),base_columns) & _),
#"Added Custom" =List.Accumulate(Combo, #table({"Column1"}, {}),(state,current)=> state & Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(Source, current)),1)),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Custom", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Added Index",{{"Column1", Order.Ascending}, {"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Sorted Rows", {"Column1"}, {{"data", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index2", 1, 1, Int64.Type), type table}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Index2","Column2", "Column3" }, { "Type","Letter", "Count"})
in  #"Expanded data"


Alternate just for fun
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each 
    let a= Record.FieldValues(_), 
    b=List.Alternate(List.RemoveFirstN(a,1),1,1), 
    c=List.Alternate(List.RemoveFirstN(a,1),1,1,1),
    d = List.Repeat({List.First(a,1)},List.Count(b)),
    e = {1 .. List.Count(b)}
    in List.Zip({d,e,c,b})),
output = Table.Transpose(Table.FromColumns(List.Combine(#"Added Custom"[Custom])))
in output


Or you can just create a sub table for each ID and then combine them:

let
  Source =  Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
  AddTableById = Table.AddColumn(Source, "TableById", each Table.FromRecords({
    [ID = [ID], Type=1, Letter=[Type 1], Count=[Count 1]],
    [ID = [ID], Type=2, Letter=[Type 2], Count=[Count 2]],
    [ID = [ID], Type=3, Letter=[Type 3], Count=[Count 3]]
})),
  Combined = Table.Combine(AddTableById[TableById])
in
  Combined

